# How to determine the number of elements of a complex array in cpp?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sizeof, complex-numbers

I have a complex number array. I want to know the number of elements in that array. For a complex number array, a pair of real and imaginary element will be considered as 1 element.

I have declared my complex array using

```
std::vector< std::complex<double> > Complex_Data
```

I have declared a macro to calculate number of elements in a simple array

```
#define ELEMENT_COUNT(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a))
```

This macro works for normal array but not complex array. How do I modify this macro or how do I write code to calculated number of elements in a complex array.

The error that I get during compilation is

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’)  
    #define ELEMENT_COUNT(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a))
```

Comment: [`std::vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size)?

Comment: `std::vector` provides a function `std::vector<T>::size()`

Comment: "This macro works for normal array" I doubt that, in case you refer to a `std::vector<something_not_complex>`. Better dont use such ancient stuff when dealing with vectors, it cannot give you the correct answer

Comment: A vector is not a dumb array.  It knows its size by utilizing the `size()` function.  There is no need for macros as you've written to determine the number of elements in a vector or any standard container.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports C++ 17 Standard then you can use the general function `std::size` declared in the header `<iterator>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> a[] = { { 1.1, 1.1 }, { 2.2, 2.2 }, { 3.3, 3.3 }, { 4.4, 4.4 }, { 5.5, 5.5 } };
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> v = { { 1.1, 1.1 }, { 2.2, 2.2 }, { 3.3, 3.3 }, { 4.4, 4.4 }, { 5.5, 5.5 } };

    std::cout << std::size( a ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::size( v ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
5
5
```

Otherwise as the class template `std::vector` is a standard container then as usual (except the class `std::forward_list`) it has a member function `size` that returns the number of elements in a vector.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> v = { { 1.1, 1.1 }, { 2.2, 2.2 }, { 3.3, 3.3 }, { 4.4, 4.4 }, { 5.5, 5.5 } };

    std::cout << v.size() << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
5
```

Pay attention to that instead of your macro you can use standard class `std::extent` declared in the header `<type_traits>` to determine the number of elements in an array.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> a[] = { { 1.1, 1.1 }, { 2.2, 2.2 }, { 3.3, 3.3 }, { 4.4, 4.4 }, { 5.5, 5.5 } };

    std::cout << std::extent_v<decltype( a )> << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
5
```

Or if the compiler does not define the construction `std::extent_v` then instead of

```
std::extent_v<decltype( a )>
```

you can write

```
std::extent<decltype( a )>::value
```